# How can I target css element inside id

Tags: html, css

**Helo**, I want to **target** (a) element inside a **css** id to **change** all (a) color inside **slidebar** id**.

> **I tried** to do this

```css
<style>
#slidebar: a {
    color: #fc7f03 !important;
}
</style>
```

but the color still blue not orange.

> **Full code:**

```html
<style>
#slidebar: a {
    color: #fc7f03 !important;
}
</style>
<div id="slidebar">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0" style=" background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #444444, #cccccc); border-radius: 30px;">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Website Name</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-speedometer2"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span> </a>
                        <ul class="collapse show nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1 </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2 </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-table"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Orders</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu2" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle ">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-bootstrap"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Bootstrap</span></a>
                        <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu2" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-grid"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Products</span> </a>
                            <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Customers</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <div class="dropdown pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="hugenerd" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">Admin</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col py-3">
            Content area...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#slidebar a` instead of `#slidebar: a`

Comment: Wow that very simple :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix it by removing : from the style part

```
<style>
    #slidebar a {
        color: #fc7f03 !important;
    }
</style>
```

good luck